# How do i run a system() command using arduino sketch program?

Tags: arduino

So, here is the thing. I have written an arduino sketch program and this is what i want say if the LED blinks then say the following code is executed such as 
system("c:\temp\capture.txt") something like that. Is there a way to do that?

```
void loop()
{
   val = digitalRead(2);
if(val == HIGH)
{
    digitalWrite(LED,HIGH)
  //system command happens here
}
}
```

How do i do that? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arduino won't be able to execute programs in PC directly because its system is isolated from PC. That's why Arduino can run programs without PC (standalone).

Consider developing a host program that run on your PC and accept comnands via serial communication, and send comnand to execute something from Arduino to the host program. Then, have the host program execute the program to run.